# Issue processing RSS feed with Perl/CURL

Tags: perl, curl, rss, nextgen-gallery

I have this RSS feed URL:

http://mediosymedia.com/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/xml/media-rss.php

A client is trying to access to this RSS programmatically via PERL like this:

```
# Fetch the content available in source HTTP URL
`curl -g --compressed "$source_url" > $tempRSSFile`;
```

Where `$source_url` is `http://mediosymedia.com/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/xml/media-rss.php`

But they said that they couldn't access the feed this way with my URL, I know nothing about PERL so, you guys could point me in the right direction to make a compatible URL for the feed?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your RSS feed. The problem is that your client doesn't know what they're doing, and you're not going to solve their problem by pondering a one-line code sample. At the least, you can ask them why they're using `curl` instead of LWP.

Comment: If you have automated defense mechanisms installed, it might good to configure them in a way that handles RSS feeds differently from normal webpages. You may want to protect pages from automated scraping – for which curl can be used – while the whole point of RSS feeds is automatic polling. If neccessary, it should be able to circumvent some defenses by spoofing the user agent string.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with perl. If you run the curl command from cmdline, then you get a `Error 406 - Not Acceptable` error. One possibility is to trick mod_security by using another User-Agent header. This works right now:

```
curl --user-agent Mozilla/5.0 -g --compressed http://mediosymedia.com/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/xml/media-rss.php > /tmp/feed.rss
```

But better, as amon already said, is to fix the server and allow RSS download also for curl.

Comment: I'll try with that, and also the suggestion from @amon

Comment: Well, the client says (they response come today) they can't use this solution because they have other feeds using this script without problems. I'm lost with this :(